# Find java virtual memory resource hog

Tags: java, servlets, memory, jvm

I'm currently facing a very strange problem. I have written a simple servlet which runs within a self hosting jetty container. This servlet is a logging endpoint for JS scripts. So the script just runs very simple code to log to graylog and some files (managed by a log4j file appender.)

The admin complained to me that the servlet hogs up to 10.5GB of Virtual Memory which caused the whole machine to slow down. This had an impact on the performance of some other monitoring services.

Restarting the servlet fixed the problem temporarly but the question is how can I find and fix spots in the code causing such memory hogging?

Edit:
I start the application with the `-Xmx50m` switch.

Edit:
The following things have been investigated: I started Eclipse Memory Analyzer and jConsole to have a look into the application while some ruby scripts sent requests. (40 to 70 requests per minute. That's more than the servlet is getting in production at the moment.)

With this setting:

- Heap size: 4MB
- Running threads average: 19 (peak at 23)
- Virtual Memory: 5GB

Restarting the servlet speeded up the server. The only suspicious parameter of the servlet were the 10.5GB Virtual Memory.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual memory doesn't use much resources, only resident memory matters.  You can create a process which uses 8 TB of virtual memory and it still has little impact on resources.

On Linux the "simplest" way to check virtual memory is to read `/proc/{pid}/mmap` even this is pretty cryptic.

I would check the resident memory and this is what really matters, but I suspect it is close to your 10.5 GB if they are complaining ( assuming they know what they are talking, which I wouldn't assume )

Answer (score 0):

> how can I find and fix spots in the code causing such memory hogging

Start by [searching this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=find%20java%20memory%20usage%20site%3astackoverflow.com). There are literally thousands of results.
For your specific case, I'd look for the following:

- An unreasonably large heap specification, using the `-Xmx` command-line argument when starting Java. For a simple servlet, you should use maybe 100-200 Mb.
- An excessive number of threads. Each thread requires space (2 Mb by default) for its internal stack.
- Large memory-mapped files. The way you describe your servlet, you shouldn't be using any of these.

Comment: -1 for pseudo-funny smartassery with google link. BTW: I'm using -Xmx50m.

Comment: @schlingel - it wasn't meant to be smart-assed, or particularly funny. You asked a question with very few details and no reason to assume any competence or research on your part. I gave you the three most likely causes of problems, and a link with more information. But if your ego was hurt, and it makes you feel better to downvote, then by all means do so. Doesn't get you any closer to solving your problem, though.

Comment: You got a downvote for a google link and labeling it "this site". That's not smart nor funny. Don't act like it wasn't meant to be. Additionally looking for Virtual Memory problems pop up a lot of Heap problems, but that isn't the case. But - few details were a fair point. Updated the question.